# $X\to Y\to Z$ is a closed immersion and $Y\to Z$ is separated, then $X\to Y$ is a closed immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X,Y,Z$ be schemes. I'm trying to prove that:

> If $X\to Y\to Z$ is a closed immersion and $Y\to Z$ is separated, then $X\to Y$ is a closed immersion

Here's where I'm at: Let $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to Z$. Since $g\circ f$ is a closed immersion, in particular $f$ is injective. Furthermore, $(g\circ f)^\#_x=f_x^\#\circ g_x^\#$ is surjective, hence $f_x^\#$ is surjective for all $x$.

The only thing left is to show that $f$ is closed. By assumption, if $F\subset X$ is closed, then $(g\circ f)(F)$ is closed.

I don't know how to conclude $f(F)$ is closed using the fact that $g$ is separated.

Is this even possible? Any suggestions are welcome, thank you!

Comment: Typo? I think you mean "therefore $f_x^{\#}$ is *surjective* for all $x$"

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, I've just corrected it, thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to prove this? Is it an exercise from a text or a course, or did you stumble on this when working on another problem?

Comment: @KReiser I was working on another problem involving base changes. I've read the claim above in a wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_immersion, section "properties"), and it suited the problem nicely

Comment: Since wikipedia stated it without any explanation, I assumed it was trivial. But I got stuck trying to prove $f$ is closed

Comment: This is a special case of the useful result which Ravki Vakil calls the Cancellation Theorem for a "reasonable" property P of morphisms, [10.1.9 in his notes](https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf). The key trick to the proof is to represent the morphism as its graph and use stability under composition and base change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the graph $\Gamma_f = (1_X,f) : X \to X \times_Z Y$ is the pullback of the diagonal $\Delta = (1_Y, 1_Y) : Y \to Y \times_Z Y$ along the map $f \times_Z 1_Y : X \times_Z Y \to Y \times_Z Y$ (check this directly). Since closed immersions are stable under base change and $\Delta$ is a closed immersion by assumption, $\Gamma_f$ is a closed immersion.

Now, $f$ factors as $\pi_2 \circ \Gamma_f$, where $\pi_2 : X \times_Z Y \to Y$ is the projection on the second factor, so it suffices to show that $\pi_2$ is a closed immersion. To do this, note that $\pi_2$ can be identified with map $(g \circ f) \times_Z 1_Y : X \times_Z Y \to Z \times_Z Y$ via the canonical identification $Y \cong Z \times_Z Y$. But $g \circ f$ is a closed immersion by assumption, and closed immersions are stable under base change, so $\pi_2$ is a closed immersion as well.

We conclude that $f = \pi_2 \circ \Gamma_f$ is the composition of two closed immersions, hence also a closed immersion.

Comment: In order to say that $\Gamma_f$ is a closed immersion by pullback of the diagonal, don't we have to prove that the diagram involving  $\Gamma_f$, $\Delta$ , $f\times_Z 1_Y$ and $f$ is cartesian? In other words, that $X\simeq Y\times_{Y\times_Z Y}(X\times_Z Y)$? That doesn't seem obvious at all

Comment: It might not be obvious but it is true! For reference, this is a special case of EGA1 5.3.5, but the proof in EGA1 is left to the reader because it's easy (and a good exercise in abstract nonsense) to verify this fact directly. I can expand my answer with a proof if you're stuck!